# How to fix 'sdk-base' and 'sdk-panowidget' error in Android studio

Tags: sdk, version, google-vr, daydream

I'm working on a software that uses daydream controller to switch VR images, using package conflicts,The package used to display the picture is 'sdk-panowidget', and the package used to control the handle is 'sdk-base'.

```java
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.wolfwang.demo_vr"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.vr:sdk-base:1.190.0'
    implementation 'com.google.vr:sdk-panowidget:1.40.0'

    api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'], exclude: [])
}
```

```java
implementation 'com.google.vr:sdk-base:1.190.0'
implementation 'com.google.vr:sdk-panowidget:1.40.0'
```

Help me solve problems